# TIP41C voltage drop

Tags: power-supply, transistors, current, npn, voltage

I have used the TIP41C in order to get a constant current source by placing a resistor in between the source and collector in the circuit below:

[image]

The sample circuit is shown where the voltage at the base gives the changes in current. I have been using a self-made power supply to power it with 5V and 15V. Here the 5V are taken from the voltage regulator in a power supply while the 15V is directly taken from the mains. But I have had many problems. First when I connect the 1 ohm resistor the voltage of the base gets 4.7 which is considerable, but at the same time the collector voltage drops from 15V to approximately 6V. I don't know what's causing this error. Secondly, suggest whether to use TIP122 or if I should continue with TIP42C.

Comment: "15V is directly taken from the mains" - really? Mains is usually about 120 VAC or 230 VAC. Where is the 15 V coming from?

Comment: It is taken from a power supply of 15V and the 5V is taken from a regulator attached at the power supply

Comment: If you put 5V at the base you are demanding that just under 5Amps flow through the collector.  I suspect that you 15V power supply is collapsing. What are the voltages across each of the two one ohm resistors?

Comment: YES it seems like the supply is collapsing and it should behave like that i guess...I am getting 3.8V at the emitter 1 ohm resistor and just for simplicity shorted the collector with the source.

Comment: @EEK21 What would you like to achieve? Keep in mind that circuits like this are typically only useful over a small range -- probably no more than a factor of three one way of the other, from the middle. And the use of a 10 k pot is another limiting factor.

Comment: "Continue with TIP42C" - which is it, 41 or 42? Please be more careful with your questions. We spend a lot of time making the answers right, please spend time to make your question right.

Comment: This is TIP41C. The TIP42C IS PNP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a table from the [ST TIP41C datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tip41c.pdf):

[image]

It tells you enough to make some good estimates of what's happening in your circuit.

First, you say you have placed the base at \$V_B=+4.7V\$. From the table above, the voltage \$V_{BE}\$ could be as high as 2V, when collector current is 6A. Being conservative, and assuming just a couple of amps of collector current, let's estimate \$V_{BE}=1.5V\$.

This places emitter potential at \$V_E = V_B - V_{BE} = +4.7V - 1.5V \approx 3V\$. That's the voltage \$V_{RE}=3V\$ across the 1Ω emitter resistor, for an emitter current \$I_E = \frac{V_E}{R_E} = \frac{3V}{1\Omega} = 3A\$.

Refer to the table again to find what the potential difference \$V_{CE}\$, between collector and emitter, would be with 3A of current. It says \$V_{CE(SAT)}=1.5V\$ at 6A, so again, lets estimate a little less, about 1V.

If the transistor were saturated, with \$V_{CE}=1.0V\$, that would place collector potential \$V_C\$ at \$V_C = V_E + V_{CE} = +3V + 1V = +4V\$. You have reported that value to be +6V, so I will hazard a guess that the transistor is *not* saturated, since \$V_{CE}=+6V-3V=+3V\$ is significantly greater than \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$.

This means that the transistor is operating in its active region, and so collector current and emitter currents are approximately equal (since base current will be small in comparison, by a factor of \$h_{FE} > 15\$).

A collector current of about \$I_C \approx I_E = 3A\$ is therefore flowing through the 1Ω collector resistor, for a voltage across it of \$V_{RC}=I_CR_C=3A\times 1\Omega = 3V\$.

By KVL we add up all the voltages across elements in the path from positive supply to ground, via the collector resistor, the transistor C-E, and emitter resistor. Here's the punchline:

$$ V_{RC} + V_{CE} + V_{RE} \approx 3V + 3V + 3V = 9V $$

This is significantly lower than the 15V supply you expected. If I were a betting man, I'd put money on your power supply being incapable of supplying those 3A of current, and is dropping out. Under a load of 3A it is only producing 9V.

I admit, that's a lot of educated guessing, but this is where I would start: check the power supply voltage. If it drops under +15V, then clearly it's being overloaded. If it stays at (or near) +15V then the problem lies elsewhere.

Here's what the circuit should do if the power supply were able to supply the full current, and stay at +15V. If the base is at +4.7V, then the emitter will be somewhere between +3V, and +4V. Current in the emitter resistor, which will be approximately the same as current in the collector resistor, will also be somewhere between 3A and 4A. This will create a voltage *across* the collector resistor of 3V to 4V. Since the power supply is at +15V, the potential \$V_C\$ at transistor's collector should be between \$V_C=+15V-4V=+11V\$, and \$V_C=+15V-3V=+12V\$.

So, get to work, measure ***all*** the potentials, calculate all the corresponding currents, and report back.

And yes, you should use a TIP122. It would give you better equality between \$I_C\$ and \$I_E\$, by reducing base current significantly. This will cause base potential to remain much more stable as collector current varies, and reduce power dissipation in the potentiometer.

Comment: Also, with a current gain of about 30, a load current of 3A will require a base current of 100 mA, but 100 mA through a 10k pot would require about 100 V. In reality, the output on the wiper of the pot will get close to its expected value of about 5 V close to the top, but it will be very non-linear under a 100 mA load, and it may be damaged, assuming a 1 watt pot with maximum current of 10 mA.

Comment: Thank you Sir. The assumption is very tricky and I sometimes think that I might be assuming wrong leading to false concepts and results that's why I usually ask ....Actually I assumed that the transistor will always be in the active some since the input voltage is less than the 15V. Thats why I didn't took the values of the saturated mode in consideration. Ill work on calculating all the values again and try to make in on another board since the breadboard doesn't seem to be the much better option.